# implementing if-else conditions on list of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following list of lists:

`[[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, -1], [3, -1], [4, -1], [5, -1], [6, -1], [7, -1]]`

I would like to have output of:

`list2 = [[0, 3], [1, 2]]`

List comprehension with an if-else statement seems to be a good option for this.

```
list2 = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list1[i])):
        if list1[i][j] != -1:
            list2.append(list1[i])
```

However, I get the following output:

```
[[0, 3],
 [0, 3],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 2],
 [2, -1],
 [3, -1],
 [4, -1],
 [5, -1],
 [6, -1],
 [7, -1]]
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! One of the most important things about a good question is you need to carefully and precisely define the criteria/logic which gives the desired result. please explain more thoroughly what you're trying to do - read your question and imagine you're us - we have no idea how to get list2 from list1.

Comment: Althought that's technically true and certainly good general advice @MichaelDelgado, from the example given by OP and their code, it seems fairly safe to assume they don't want elements from the first list in the second if either element is -1. The input list is missing an element starting with -1 (and not ending in it). The question would definitely be clearer with a description of the desired result in addition to the example and the code itself, but I think it's perfectly answereable as it is.

Comment: I agree from a common sense deduction perspective. However, drawing sure conclusion from non-working example could be contradictory.

Comment: @Grismar - sure, and you did answer it. With my comment I was in fact intending to give general advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this line was missing from your example:

```
list1 = [[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, -1], [3, -1], [4, -1], [5, -1], [6, -1], [7, -1]]
```

Have a close look at your code:

```
list2 = []
for i in range(len(list1)):         # ranging from 0 to 7
    for j in range(len(list1[i])):  # 8 times, ranging from 0 to 1
        if list1[i][j] != -1:       # checks one element, (0,0), (0,1), etc.
            list2.append(list1[i])  # if that one element is not -1, add it
```

So, the problem is that you don't check if either element is -1, or if only the last element is -1, and then add it.

You add it whenever you find either element not to be -1. So, `[0, 3]` gets added twice, first because `0` isn't `-1` and again because `3` isn't `-1`. `[2, -1]` gets added once, because `2` isn't `-1`. Only `[-1, -1]` would never be added.

You appear to want to add one of the sublists "if none of its elements are -1",  so:

```
if -1 not in list1[i]:
    list2.append[list[i]]   # for some i, ranging over all indices of list1
```

And the solution:

```
list2 = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if -1 not in list1[i]:
        list2.append(list1[i])
```

However, there's far more efficient and easier to read solutions to this in Python. For one, you can loop over the elements of a list without using an index. Secondly, instead of creating a list one part at a time with `.append`, you can use a so-called list comprehension.

So, the same:

```
list2 = [part for part in list1 if -1 not in part]
```

However, all those solutions have another problem you may run into later. You're not creating a new list with copies of the original sublists - you're creating a new list that has the actual same sublists in there. If you change an element of `list2`, you will be changing the same list in `list1` as well.

If you don't want that, you'll need to create a copy of the lists you're adding, for example:

```
list2 = [list(part) for part in list1 if -1 not in part]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to only add items without a -1 in them.

The inner for loop is checking the numbers inside the sub lists.
For example, with [0, 3] it checks the 0, sees it's not -1, and adds it the output. The same happens with the 3 and hence it shows up twice in list2. If you had [-1, -1] it would not be added. [0, 4, 3, 5, -1, 4] would be added 5 times.

Instead, what you want is `not -1 in list[i]`, or in the full code it would be

```py
list1 = [[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, -1], [3, -1], [4, -1], [5, -1], [6, -1], [7, -1]]
list2 = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if not -1 in list1[i]:
        list2.append(list1[i])
```

Comment: No need for range() ... Just use `for item in list1: if not -1 in item: list2.append(item)`

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
lst = [[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, -1], [3, -1], [4, -1], [5, -1], [6, -1], [7, -1]]
res = []
for a in lst:
    if a[1] != -1:
        res.append(a)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to extract couples which do not contain `-1`. Please, specify your aim more carefully.

In that case, in one line:

```
list1=[[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, -1], [3, -1], [4, -1], [5, -1], [6, -1], [7, -1]]
out=[[x,y] for x,y in list1 if not -1 in (x,y)]
```

By doing this, you can directly filter the couples that make the top level list with a list comprehension, as you pointed out